# PHPExcel Error: Scale must be greater than or equal to 1

Tags: php, phpexcel

I believe this to be an error with how the Excel File .xlsx is being generated which we unfortunately have no control over since it's through a 3rd party API. Every Time I try and ope the file using...

```
    try {
            $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
            $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
            $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
        }
```

I get an error spit out that says 'filename.xlst': PHPExcel Error: Scale must be greater than or equal to 1. I am guessing that when they are generating the Excel file they are setting an illegal value for the zoom scale. I can get this same file to work by converting it to a csv and then back to a xlsx which I assume sets the zoom scale on the document back to the default.

The issue is this is a pain for end users and I can't seem to find a way in the documentation to override the zoomscale setting when I am loading in the file.

Any Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So like we had thought we had some illegal characters. What my coworker who was working on this with me did was find a XLSX to CSV converter and rewrote a little bit and add it in as a composer package. If anyone else runs into this issue the repo is here. I'll try and add some docs soon.

https://github.com/StudentAffairsUWM/xlsxtocsv

Answer (score 0):

I get this exception
Problem was in xlsx file, parameter `zoomScaleNormal` in xml sheet description was 0, but this is error.
If save this file from excel, error has gone away.
In my case i am edit file Reader/Excel2007.php

```
   if (isset($xmlSheet->sheetViews->sheetView['zoomScaleNormal'])) {
        if (intval($xmlSheet->sheetViews->sheetView['zoomScaleNormal']) === 0)
            $zoomScaleNormal = 85;
        else{
            $zoomScaleNormal = intval($xmlSheet->sheetViews->sheetView['zoomScaleNormal']);
        }
        $docSheet->getSheetView()->setZoomScaleNormal( $zoomScaleNormal );
    }
```

I am add condition, if zoomScaleNormal = 0, i am set it to 85

Answer (score 0):

Same happens to me today. Add additional check to `Reader/Excel5.php` on line `4325`:

```
    if ($fPageLayoutView === 1) {
        $this->_phpSheet->getSheetView()->setView(PHPExcel_Worksheet_SheetView::SHEETVIEW_PAGE_LAYOUT);
        if ($wScalePLV == 0) $wScalePLV = 100; // <<<<< ADD THIS CHECK
        $this->_phpSheet->getSheetView()->setZoomScale($wScalePLV); //set by Excel2007 only if SHEETVIEW_PAGE_LAYOUT
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to latest PhpSpreadsheet version (or at least v1.2.0).

This has been solved via https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/pull/350.