# PHPSpreadsheet: Scale must be greater than or equal to 1

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

When I try to open/read the spreadsheet (xls), I get the following error:

> Scale must be greater than or equal to 1

I am using the following code to open and read the file:

```
$filename = 'test.xls';
$spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($filename); //<-- ERRORS HERE
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
```

The error occurs on the `::load` command.

It isn't a data issue - I can copy the existing data into a new file and it works correctly, so must be an issue with the file itself.

I am using v1.6.0 of PHPSpreadsheet, which is the latest at time of writing.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

This question relates to PHPSpreadsheet, not PHPExcel as listed here:
[PHPExcel Error: Scale must be greater than or equal to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915792/phpexcel-error-scale-must-be-greater-than-or-equal-to-1)

Though similar, an XLSX version of my file works as expected, hence the need to create a separate question. PHPExcel is also now marked as officially dead, so seems logical to add this question to the correct library / tag on SO.

I have since found a solution to the problem (added below), which *may* also work in PHPExcel, but comes with no warranties!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPExcel Error: Scale must be greater than or equal to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915792/phpexcel-error-scale-must-be-greater-than-or-equal-to-1)

Comment: @NicoHaase It's a similar issue, but a different library. That relates to PHPExcel - this is PHPSpreadsheet.

Comment: `PHPSpreadsheet` is just a more current version of `PHPExcel`

Comment: @NicoHaase Perhaps, but the codebase is different - the files referenced in that answer don't exist in PHPSpreadsheet. I am also using XLS - an XLSX version of my file works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have found a solution to my particular problem...

It requires an edit to the `setZoomScale` function which can be found in `SheetView.php`.

The zoomscale in my file had a value of zero, which threw an error. The new code checks for this and if found, sets it to 1.

Perhaps not ideal solution for everyone, but works in a pinch:

```
public function setZoomScale($pValue)
{
    /* NEW code that sets the zoom scale 
    ------------------------------------------*/

    //Zoom Scale of 0 causes error. If found, default pValue to 1.
    if( $pValue == 0)
    {
        $pValue = 1;
    }

    /*----------------------------------------*/

    // Microsoft Office Excel 2007 only allows setting a scale between 10 and 400 via the user interface,
    // but it is apparently still able to handle any scale >= 1
    if (($pValue >= 1) || $pValue === null) 
    {
        $this->zoomScale = $pValue;
    } 
    else 
    {
        throw new PhpSpreadsheetException('Scale must be greater than or equal to 1.');
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: If that solved your problem without breaking anything else, could you write a bug report for that library to include your fix? This ensures that you can perform upgrades to later versions

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
$spreadsheet = \IOFactory::load($filename);
```

Comment: Please explain the difference in your code - why is it neccessary to solve the given error message?